# completly removing a package of this kind

Tags: repository

hi I was trying to configure my laptop and went online trying to figure out about things to do after installing Ubuntu 14.04. I came across this.

> Fix overheating and extend battery life
>
> There is a good chance Ubuntu is not handling your fan, battery, etc. optimally but there is a nifty utility that probably will. Do this:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
> sudo tlp start

but it seems to have made my laptop behaving weirdly but shutting down regularly after booting an entering password. how do I remove the whole package? please.

Also my graphics seem to turn a bit greyish for a mn or two before returning to normal.

I am using a Lenovo w510 Intel core i7 with 4gb ram and 1tb hdd.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Installs PPA Purge

`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

Removes the PPA

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:linrunner/tlp`

Uninstalls the packages

`sudo apt-get purge tlp tlp-rdw`

Restart system. Optionally, if there are no open documents etc, `shutdown -r 0` for a quick reboot.